# How to pass value to an optional property in another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to pass a date value from a view controller via the `prepare(forSegue: ...)` method to a date picker modal which has an optional `minimumDate` and `maximumDate` property. But the value from view controller 1 is not received in the modal. Here's a sample code of what I am trying to do:

View controller 1:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "modal_datePicker"{
        let datePickerModal = segue.destination as! modal_dateTimePickerVC
        datePickerModal.isDatePicker = true
        datePickerModal.maximumDate = Date()
    }
}
```

View controller 2 (the date picker modal):

```
var minimumDate: Date?
var maximumDate: Date?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if minimumDate != nil { //if minimum date was specified
        picker_workoutDateTime.minimumDate = minimumDate
    }

    if maximumDate != nil{
        picker_workoutDateTime.maximumDate = maximumDate
        print("Maximum date specified \(maximumDate)")
    }else{
        print("Maximum date NOT specified")
    }   
}
```

In the code above, I am trying to put in the current date by assigning `Date()` to the `.maximumDate` property from the prepare for segue method in View Controller 1. In view controller 2, I check to see if either the `maximumDate` and `minimumDate` was provided using an `IF` statement, checking if their values are nil. It seems that the value from view controller 1 is not being received by view controller 2.

The whole reason why I did it this way is to make this modal dialog (view controller 2) reusable. Such that if the user specifies a minimum or maximum dates, then the user can only pick from a certain date range. But if it's not specified, then it will allow the user to pick any date.

Comment: what is your date? the Date() just create an empty class there is nothing to pass

Comment: @taratandel Date() without passing any parameters creates a Date object based on the current date and time.

Comment: it creates an object but its empty so checking for nil will return true

Comment: Again, `Date()` is not the same as nil. It is a date object based on the current date and time. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1780470-init

Comment: That's correct, Date() without parameters creates a date object with the current date and time. Therefore if I check for nil, it will return false because it's not nil, it's been initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to check:

1. "View controller 1" is not passing a `minimumDate` to "View controller 2".
2. Does your segue have the identifier correctly specified? Can you check if the following line of code in the `prepare for segue` method returns true?

   ```
   if segue.identifier == "modal_datePicker"{
   ```
3. Does "View Controller 2" have the identifier or subclass correctly specified? I assume this is `modal_dateTimePickerVC`.

Some advice that probably won't help this particular issue, but worth mentioning:

1. In general class names should start with a capital letter and use camel case, i.e. `ModalDateTimePickerVC` instead of `modal_dateTimePickerVC`.
2. In general you should try to use optional binding rather than forced unwrapping, eg:

   ```
   if let datePickerModal = segue.destination as? modal_dateTimePickerVC {
   ```

Comment: Gosh, silly me! You're #2 point saved the day! :-D I used the wrong segue identifier! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should assign value to second view properties in `prepareForSegue` method, like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "modal_datePicker"{
        let datePickerModal = segue.destination as! modal_dateTimePickerVC
        datePickerModal.maximumDate = Date()
        datePickerModal.minimumDate = 'some Date'
    }
}
```

The `isDatePicker` is the boolean value of `UIDatePicker` and not property of vc unless you defined it as a property in your second viewController.

Answer (score 0):

```
if let viewControllerObject = UIStoryboard(name: "viewControllerName", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewControllerName") as? viewControllerName {
           viewControllerObject.OptionalValueObject = "Data or string to pass"
    }
```

you can do this to pass data between 2 viewControllers

- to push the viewController you can user this -

  navigationController?.pushViewController(viewControllerObject, animated: true)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem using segues. For some reason passed data was accessible only inside `viewWillAppear` method instead of `viewDidLoad`.

It is better to pass such values inside initializer. Unfortunately, you can't do this using segues. But you can avoid this by presenting controller manually and passing optional values inside init method of `viewController`.

```
func presentPicker() {
    let pickerVC = ModalDateTimePickerVC(asDatePicker: false, minDate: nil, maxDate: nil)
    self.present(pickerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

class ModalDateTimePickerVC: UIViewController {
    var minimumDate: Date?
    var maximumDate: Date?
    var isDatePicker: Date

    init(asDatePicker isDatePicker: Bool, minDate: Date? = nil, maxDate: Date? = nil) {
        self.isDatePicker = isDatePicker
        self.minimumDate = minDate
        self.maximumDate = maxDate
    }
}
```

You can also omit optional parameters and call initializer like `ModalDateTimePickerVC(asDatePicker: true)`